# Qt : keyboard focus

Tags: qt, focus, keyboard-events, qwidget

I am writing a program in Qt that looks like this:

[image: Screen Capture]

The main window is my class `Window : QWidget`, it has a `QGridLayout` containing four other widgets (`Input_Menu : QWidget` and `Output_Menu : QWidget`, and then two `Canvas : QWidget`)

I would like to trigger certain events when the user strikes a key. The problem is, the `Window` sometimes loses focus (it goes, say to `Input_Menu`, or maybe a button in `Input_Menu`...)

I have tried the following solutions, but they seem unsatisfactory (and dirty):

1. Give `Window` the focus whenever it loses it.
2. Tell each widget who could have the focus to trigger `Window`'s `KeyPressEvent` function (or a clone of it) whenever it receives a keyboard event.

Ideally, I would like that if a widget receives an event (say a keyboard event) and doesn't know what to do with it, it should automatically call its parent's event handler. I would have hoped this to be a default feature of Qt but it doesn't look like it. On the other hand I am really confused about the whole focus thing, I don't really get what's going on. Can someone explain this to me: I have included a `std::cout << "key pressed" << std::endl;` in my `Window::KeyPressEvent` function. When I first run my program, it seems the focus is on the top QComboBox in `Input_Menu`: if I hit the Up/Down keys, I navigate in that box and no "key pressed" is showed in my console. If I hit most letters, nothing happens. But if I hit Left/Right keys, I do get a "key pressed" in my console!?

Thanks a lot in advance for your insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found that for keys that are *modifiers* (such as Shift, Control), Qt supports finding out whether they are pressed.

Eg : `if(QApplication::keyboardModifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier)` ...

This is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an event filter on `QApplication` to filter the relevant `QEvent::KeyPress` events globally. From the Qt documentation:

> It is also possible to filter all events for the entire application,
>   by installing an event filter on the QApplication or QCoreApplication
>   object. Such global event filters are called before the
>   object-specific filters. This is very powerful, but it also slows down
>   event delivery of every single event in the entire application; the
>   other techniques discussed should generally be used instead.

Besides the performance considerations, remember to check if your window currently has the focus before you filter the key event, or you might break popup dialogs or input into other windows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is interesting, but unfortunately I don't think I want to do this in my specific case.